# How to use Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim plugin in React without react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, leaflet

I am using Leaflet in a React Project, and i want to import a plugin which extends Leaflet Polyline which is [Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim)

I am not using react-leaflet but directly the Javascript library, here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.polyline.snakeanim';

class LeafletMap extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    this.map = L.map('leafletMap', {
      center:[0,0], 
      zoom: 2
    });

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(this.map);

    let polylinePoints = [
      [57.74, 11.94],
      [0,0],
      [22,22]
    ];

    L.polyline(polylinePoints, {
      color: 'blue',
      weight: 8
    }).addTo(this.map).snakeIn();

   }
}
```

In my IDE, I got a warning on `snakeIn()` saying the function is unresolved. And the plugin don't work at all.

How can I properly import a Leaflet Plugin into React ?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: no I am using JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger the animation when the map loads then place the snake logic inside `componentDidMount` otherwise save the `mapInstance` when the map loads and then , using a button, trigger the snake animation inside `componentDidUpdate`.

```
class LeafletMap extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mapInstance: null,
    startAnimation: false
  };

  startSnake = () => this.setState({ startAnimation: true });

  componentDidMount() {
    const map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    this.setState({ mapInstance: map });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.startAnimation !== this.state.startAnimation) {
      const trd = [63.5, 11];
      const mad = [40.5, -3.5];
      const lnd = [51.5, -0.5];
      const ams = [52.3, 4.75];
      const vlc = [39.5, -0.5];

      const route = L.featureGroup([
        L.marker(trd, { icon }),
        L.polyline([trd, ams]),
        L.marker(ams, { icon }),
        L.polyline([ams, lnd]),
        L.marker(lnd, { icon }),
        L.polyline([lnd, mad]),
        L.marker(mad, { icon }),
        L.polyline([mad, vlc]),
        L.marker(vlc, { icon })
      ]);

      this.state.mapInstance.fitBounds(route.getBounds());

      this.state.mapInstance.addLayer(route);

      route.snakeIn();

      route.on("snakestart snake snakeend", ev => {
        console.log(ev.type);
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div id="map" style={{ height: "90vh" }} />
        <button onClick={this.startSnake}>Snake it!</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-use-snakeanim-with-react-without-react-leaflet-in222?file=/src/LeafletMap.jsx:181-1707)

Comment: Awsome ! Thank you very much, it works. I don't know why I still have the warning in my IDE but doesn't matter, the animation is well displayed.

Comment: Welcome. Not sure why you get a warning. On the demo there is no warning in the console.